# How to get diffstat in magit revision buffer?

Tags: magit

In MacOS Mojave, I am using magit version 20190319.1911, emacs v26.1, git v2.20.1 (Apple Git-117).

How do I get a diffstat in a magit revision buffer? I remember seeing such a diffstat in this buffer, but can't get it now. When I type j in a revision buffer, the response is "no diffstat in this buffer". I can get a diffstat in the log buffer, but I would prefer it in the revision buffer that is automatically updated as I move through commits in the log buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type <kbd>D</kbd> to show a popup buffer with the diff arguments used in the current buffer. Change the arguments and then type <kbd>g</kbd> to refresh the buffer using the selected arguments. Note that you can also set with <kbd>s</kbd> or save (*w*rite) with <kbd>w</kbd> the arguments for future use.

Comment: That works! Thanks.